# Geometry Nodes - Get Object Origin From Object in Collection?

Tags: mesh, node-editor, objects, geometry-nodes, collections

Quick question for all those more versed in Geometry Nodes than I am.
I want to pick an object from a collection by it's instance index and place it at the origin of whatever object is using this geo node setup:

[image: A geo node setup I'm using to put one object from a collection at a point in space dynamically via it's instance index.]

Right now, I'm able to do this with some inverse calculations upon the bounding box of the output outlined in red, but what I'd really like to do is get the object origin of the output outlined in red, even though by this point its not an 'object' but just mere geometric data, so that I can retain the offset the mesh data might have from the origin of the picked object that mesh data belongs to.

Is there any way I can achieve what I described even if completely alien to my current node setup?

Many thanks for reading!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply reset the transformations of the instances, so their locations are $<0, 0, 0>$, then pick the one of interest.

[image]

Comment: That seems to have done it, TYSM! Sorry for the late reply, got caught up last night in other matters than had work all of today : )